# How to know if all NULL for a column in all rows of result recordset in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, wordpress

Let's say my resulting recordset is as follows:

```
Emp_ID    ID    Ability    Rating
------    --    -------    ------
NULL      DRI   Driving    NULL
NULL      TYP   Typing     NULL
NULL      GRA   Graphics   NULL
NULL      VID   Video      NULL
NULL      GAM   Gaming     NULL
```

while another case could be:

```
Emp_ID    ID    Ability    Rating
------    --    -------    ------
15        DRI   Driving    7
15        TYP   Typing     6
15        GRA   Graphics   8
15        VID   Video      7
15        GAM   Gaming     10
```

or:

```
Emp_ID    ID    Ability    Rating
------    --    -------    ------
22        DRI   Driving    4
NULL      TYP   Typing     NULL
NULL      GRA   Graphics   NULL
22        VID   Video      8
22        GAM   Gaming     5
```

What's my **least costly** way in PHP to check if `Emp_ID` is all `NULL` like the first one?

`Emp_ID` is `BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED` (and `Rating` is `TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED`) in MySQL. The recordset is returned by `$wpdb_custom->get_results()`.

Comment: _Why_ do you need to determine if `Emp_ID` is null?  Is this to handle some special case?  Could this be handled on the database side (say, through the use of `COALESCE()`)?

Comment: hi @X-Zero yeap, totally a special case i have no control over. :/ i know this should be done server-side, but that's just not an option right now. sorry. any suggestions? thanks much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$all_null = true;
foreach($wpdb->get_results() as $row) {
    if(!is_null($row['Emp_ID'])) {
        $all_null = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

Since you can't edit the query, the best you can do is just iterate over the results checking for null.  But the important thing is to `break` when you find a non-null row.  At that point you know that not all rows are null, so don't bother iterating over the remaining rows.

Comment: totally makes sense. will update this question once i finalize stuff and see what works best with the current setup. thanks, @ben

Answer (score 2):

You could do that in SQL so that you don't even have to process the data in PHP. You could just use your existing SQL query followed by `AND Emp_ID IS NOT NULL;`. If you get any rows back, then you know you have some non-null rows. If you get none back, then they must have all been null.

Comment: thanks @Jeff unfortunately, i don't have that option. i need to work with this returned recordset. it's just something i can't control. but thanks much for the input. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The php way is to iterate the array

```
$аll_null = TRUE;
foreach($result as $one) $аll_null = $аll_null AND ($one->Emp_ID === NULL);
var_dump($аll_null);
```

Edit:

I'm sure that the method `get_results` also uses iteration so you can extend your `$wpdb_custom` class with another method like this:

```
public function get_results_custom($key, $test, &$result)
{
  * * *
  $result = TRUE
  while($row = do_some_iteration())
  {
    $result = $result AND $test($row->$key);
    * * *
  }
}
```

so now you can do:

```
$all_null = TRUE;
$my_data = $wpdb_custom->get_results_custom('Emp_ID', 'is_null', $all_null);
if($all_null) ...
```

Comment: In case your result is array instead of object you have to change `$one->Emp_ID` to `$one['Emp_ID']`.

Comment: totally going for this if there's no other way to do it without iteration. thanks @core1024 :D

Comment: hmm.. i checked out the wp core files and all i could find for `get_results` is `function get_results() {
  return $this->results;
 }` on line 606 of `wp-includes\user.php`, and nothing for the method `results`. is `results` a native php/mysql method? anyone out there who can check this?